# RecyclerView not working properly on layout change

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have a simple recycler view consisting of Relative layouts. The layouts presently don't have anything in them except adding a text view at `OnBindViewHolder();`
The list seems to be working fine in portrait mode but when I switch to landscape and try scrolling, the textviews overlap and create a strange look.

[image: In landscape mode after scrolling]
In landscape mode
[image: Appears normal in portrait mode]
In portrait mode.
Code:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_layout,parent,false);
    context = parent.getContext();

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(mDataSet.get(position));
    tv.setTextSize(20);
    tv.setPadding(5,20,5,20);
    holder.mLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

Above is my adapter and below is the activity from which I am calling -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(dataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.refreshDrawableState();
    //testing
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        dataset.add("Data "+(i+1));
}
```

I have already tried doing `refreshDrawableState();` on config change and adding config changes to the manifest. No avail.

Comment: Do you listen for onOrientationChanged? This may happen.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I was listening for config changes in my main activity. Nevermind though, the problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep you text view as part of your list item layout.

```
class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv;
        ViewHolder(View v){
            tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(<textview_id>);
       }
}
```

Then change the code in `onBindViewHolder()`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv.setTextSize(20);
    holder.tv.setPadding(5,20,5,20);
    holder.tv.setText(mDataSet.get(position));
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create new TextView and use `addView` method inside of `onBindViewHolder`.
This callback will be called multiple times on each ViewHolder instances, and therefore multiple TextViews will be added.

Your TextView should be part of the `recycler_layout` instead.